# Insert picture for each answer option when loading new page for a quiz in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have created a quiz with HTML, CSS and Javascript. It loads questions which are inside a specific file, such as "questionExecutivo.js", "questionLegislativo.js" and "questionJudiciario.js". The file that has the code for loading the quiz is "quiz-script.js".

I would like to load not only questions and answers options, but also an image for each of the answers options. But I can't insert these images inside HTML, because it would stay static and wouldn't consider the content of "question[something].js" file.

I believe, I should insert the image with the "quiz-script.js" file, but I don't know how I can do it.

The code is not only below, but also on my GitHub [https://github.com/gabrielacaesar/jogo-tres-poderes].

The website is https://gabrielacaesar.github.io/jogo-tres-poderes/

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Gabriela Caesar">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Jogo dos Três Poderes</title>
 <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="quizContainer" class="container">
   <div id="tela1" class="wholeScreen">
    <h1 class="opening flex green fontStyle">Jogo dos Três Poderes</h1>
    <div id="question" class="question flex"></div>
    <div class="questGroup">
     <div class="quest">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Wplkdy49hE_Q-P9hZEfzZA.png">
      <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" /><span id="opt1"></span></label>
     </div>

     <div class="quest">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Wplkdy49hE_Q-P9hZEfzZA.png">
      <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="2" /><span id="opt2"></span></label>
     </div>

     <div class="quest">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Wplkdy49hE_Q-P9hZEfzZA.png">
      <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="3" /><span id="opt3"></span></label>
     </div>

     <div class="quest">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Wplkdy49hE_Q-P9hZEfzZA.png">
      <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="4" /><span id="opt4"></span></label> 
     </div>
    <div class="button">
     <button id="nextButton" class="next-btn buttonStyle" onclick="loadNextQuestion()"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

   
  </div>
  <div id="result" class="container result" style="display:none;"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="questionExecutivo.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="quiz-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// code created by VerkkoNet's YouTube Channel
// watch the tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcucHCNPT1Y&index=148&list=WL

var currentQuestion = 0;
var score = 0;
var totQuestions = questions.length;

var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var opt4 = document.getElementById('opt4');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');

function loadQuestion (questionindex){
    var q = questions[questionindex];
    questionEl.textContent = (questionindex + 1) + '. ' + q.question;
    opt1.textContent = q.option1;
    opt2.textContent = q.option2;
    opt3.textContent = q.option3;
    opt4.textContent = q.option4;
}

function loadNextQuestion () {
    var selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
    if(!selectedOption){
        alert('Por favor, escolha uma das alternativas');
        return;
    }
    var answer = selectedOption.value;
    if(questions[currentQuestion].answer == answer){
        score += 10;
    }
    selectedOption.checked = false;
    currentQuestion++;
    if(currentQuestion == totQuestions - 1) {
        nextButton.textContent = 'Ver resultado';
    }
    if(currentQuestion == totQuestions){
       container.style.display = 'none';
       resultCont.style.display = '';
       resultCont.textContent = 'Sua pontuação: ' + score;
       return;
    }
    loadQuestion(currentQuestion);

}
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

```js
var questions = [{
 "question": "Quem comanda a Secretaria de Governo?",
 "option1": "Antonio Imbassahy",
 "option2": "Carlos Marun",
 "option3": "Sérgio Etchegoyen",
 "option4": "Geddel Vieira Lima",
 "answer": "2"
}, {
 "question": "Quem é o atual ministro da Casa Civil?",
 "option1": "Eliseu Padilha",
 "option2": "Ricardo Barros",
 "option3": "Nelson Marquezelli",
 "option4": "Ronaldo Caiado",
 "answer": "1"
}, {
 "question": "Quem é o atual ministro de Minas e Energia?",
 "option1": "Fernando Coelho Filho",
 "option2": "Edison Lobão",
 "option3": "Romero Jucá",
 "option4": "Dyogo Oliveira",
 "answer": "1"
}, {
 "question": "Quem chefia a Advocacia-Geral da União?",
 "option1": "Raquel Dodge",
 "option2": "Cármen Lúcia",
 "option3": "Grace Mendonça",
 "option4": "Mariana Carvalho",
 "answer": "3"
}]
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Rubik|Signika|Barrio');


* {
 box-sizing: none;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.fontStyle {
 font-family: 'Barrio', cursive, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.flex {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.opening {
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 60px;
}

#tela1 {
 background-image: url("alvoradaBetoBarataPR7maio2017edited2.jpg");
 height: 95vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#tela1 .openingBlock {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 250px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#tela1 button {
 margin-top: 20px;
 border-style: none;
}

#tela1.wholeScreen {
 height: 100vh;
}

.white {
 color: white;
}

.green {
 color: #01BA6A;
}

.blue {
 color: #0B0B61;
}

.fa.fa-play-circle {
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-size: 40px;
}

#poderes a {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.poder {
 width: 60%;
 height: 15%;
 font-size: 30px;
 align-self: center;
 border-radius: 2%;
 background-color: #00EC85;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;
}

.question {
 margin-top: 45px;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;
}

.questGroup {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.quest {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

.quest img {
 width: 70%;
}

.option span {
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.button {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.buttonStyle {
 width: 350px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 3%;
 background-color: #0B0B61;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
}

footer {
 background-color: #32353F;
 color: white;
 height: 40px;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 align-items: center;
}

footer i {
 margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow your code correctly, you are already setting up the questions as JSON data. So why not add the image as part of the JSON object. I added an example to your first question in the snippet below.

I also used `querySelectorAll` to add all placeholder images to an array. You might want to do the same to the placeholder options to help reduce the code a bit.

You can also set an initial `src` for the placeholder images (like an image with your site's logo as a watermark). For now, I just hide all images with `opacity:0` when none is available.

Out of interest, the norm would be to generate HTML for the entire question via `Document.createElement()`. However, there is value in how you did set it up, as it makes use of a visual template. You should weight out pros and cons of the two versions.

NB: I commented out your included script files and added their content in the JavaScript snippet area for the example. I also had to modify the styles slightly.

```js
var questions = [{
  "question": "Quem comanda a Secretaria de Governo?",
  
  "option1": "Antonio Imbassahy",
  "image1": "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Wplkdy49hE_Q-P9hZEfzZA.png",
  
  "option2": "Carlos Marun",
  "image2": "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Wplkdy49hE_Q-P9hZEfzZA.png",
  
  "option3": "Sérgio Etchegoyen",
  "image3": "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Wplkdy49hE_Q-P9hZEfzZA.png",
  
  "option4": "Geddel Vieira Lima",
  "image4": "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Wplkdy49hE_Q-P9hZEfzZA.png",
  
 "answer": "2"
}, {
 "question": "Quem é o atual ministro da Casa Civil?",
 "option1": "Eliseu Padilha",
 "option2": "Ricardo Barros",
 "option3": "Nelson Marquezelli",
 "option4": "Ronaldo Caiado",
 "answer": "1"
}, {
 "question": "Quem é o atual ministro de Minas e Energia?",
 "option1": "Fernando Coelho Filho",
 "option2": "Edison Lobão",
 "option3": "Romero Jucá",
 "option4": "Dyogo Oliveira",
 "answer": "1"
}, {
 "question": "Quem chefia a Advocacia-Geral da União?",
 "option1": "Raquel Dodge",
 "option2": "Cármen Lúcia",
 "option3": "Grace Mendonça",
 "option4": "Mariana Carvalho",
 "answer": "3"
}]



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// code created by VerkkoNet's YouTube Channel
// watch the tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcucHCNPT1Y&index=148&list=WL

var currentQuestion = 0;
var score = 0;
var totQuestions = questions.length;

var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var optImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var opt4 = document.getElementById('opt4');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');

function loadQuestion (questionindex){
    var q = questions[questionindex];

    questionEl.textContent = (questionindex + 1) + '. ' + q.question;
    for(var x=0, imgcount=optImgs.length; x<imgcount; x++){
     var src = q['image'+(x+1)];
     if(src){
       optImgs[x].style.opacity = 1;
       optImgs[x].src = src;
     }else{
       optImgs[x].style.opacity = 0;
       optImgs[x].src = "";
     }
    }
    opt1.textContent = q.option1;
    opt2.textContent = q.option2;
    opt3.textContent = q.option3;
    opt4.textContent = q.option4;
}

function loadNextQuestion () {
    var selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
    if(!selectedOption){
        alert('Por favor, escolha uma das alternativas');
        return;
    }
    var answer = selectedOption.value;
    if(questions[currentQuestion].answer == answer){
        score += 10;
    }
    selectedOption.checked = false;
    currentQuestion++;
    if(currentQuestion == totQuestions - 1) {
        nextButton.textContent = 'Ver resultado';
    }
    if(currentQuestion == totQuestions){
       container.style.display = 'none';
       resultCont.style.display = '';
       resultCont.textContent = 'Sua pontuação: ' + score;
       return;
    }
    loadQuestion(currentQuestion);

}
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Rubik|Signika|Barrio');


* {
 box-sizing: none;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.fontStyle {
 font-family: 'Barrio', cursive, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 30px;
}

/*
.flex {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
*/

.opening {
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 60px;
}

#tela1 {
 background-image: url("alvoradaBetoBarataPR7maio2017edited2.jpg");
 height: 95vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#tela1 .openingBlock {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 250px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#tela1 button {
 margin-top: 20px;
 border-style: none;
}

#tela1.wholeScreen {
 height: 100vh;
}

.white {
 color: white;
}

.green {
 color: #01BA6A;
}

.blue {
 color: #0B0B61;
}

.fa.fa-play-circle {
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-size: 40px;
}

#poderes a {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.poder {
 width: 60%;
 height: 15%;
 font-size: 30px;
 align-self: center;
 border-radius: 2%;
 background-color: #00EC85;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;
}

.question {
 margin-top: 45px;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;
}

.questGroup {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.quest {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right:25px;
}

.quest img {
 width: 70%;
}

.option span {
 color: pink;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.button {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.buttonStyle {
 width: 350px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 3%;
 background-color: #0B0B61;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
}

footer {
 background-color: #32353F;
 color: white;
 height: 40px;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Rubik', 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 align-items: center;
}

footer i {
 margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Gabriela Caesar">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Jogo dos Três Poderes</title>
 <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="quizContainer" class="container">
   <div id="tela1" class="wholeScreen">
    <h1 class="opening flex green fontStyle">Jogo dos Três Poderes</h1>
    <div id="question" class="question flex"></div>
    <div class="questGroup">
     <div class="quest">
      <img class="image" />
      <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" /><span id="opt1"></span></label>
     </div>

     <div class="quest">
      <img class="image" />
      <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="2" /><span id="opt2"></span></label>
     </div>

     <div class="quest">
      <img class="image" />
      <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="3" /><span id="opt3"></span></label>
     </div>

     <div class="quest">
      <img class="image" />
      <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="4" /><span id="opt4"></span></label> 
     </div>
    <div class="button">
     <button id="nextButton" class="next-btn buttonStyle" onclick="loadNextQuestion()"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

   
  </div>
  <div id="result" class="container result" style="display:none;"></div>
  <!--
 <script type="text/javascript" src="questionExecutivo.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="quiz-script.js"></script>
  -->
</body>
</html>
```